# How to position the cursor inside the round brackets of function (Vim editor)?

Tags: vim

While writing a C program in Vim editor, suppose I want to edit the argument list of a function for example:

```
int show_user_data(float num){
        //Some code
        //more code
}
```

My cursor currently blinking on **i** of the *int* in

`int show_user_data(float num){`

How do I bring my cursor directly inside the argument list of the function i.e inside the round brackets so that it is now blinking (better going into insert mode also) at the **f** of *float*   such that I am ready to edit the argument list already.

Comment: Why not just `3w` ?

Comment: I dont know why I didn't think of that . Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `%` will bring you to the next "match item", which is `)` in this case (see `:h 'matchpairs'`).

Now, when the cursor is on the right paren, you can do `%a` to get to the left one and enter insert mode.

So, it takes only 3 keystrokes: <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>%</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Or you can search for `(` character: <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. Three keystrokes too.

Answer (score 1):

There will be many ways based on user preference and habit. 
For your example code, I would simply do

```
ffi
```

`f` will take you to first character which follows it, here `f` and `i` for insert